# I'm struggling to remove this error from my function where it says that the function shouldn't call 'readlines'

Tags: python, computer-science

I'm struggling to remove this error from my function where it says that the function shouldn't call 'readlines'

Can someone please help me I've been trying to fix this error and couldn't solve it?

I have listed below:

1. The number.txt file that we have to work on for this code
2. what I'm being tested on, aka the conditions I have to follow
3. my code
4. the sample testing

so my question is clear to understand.

**Work with the numbers.txt file in this question.**

```
1

2

6

7

3

4

5

6

7

8

9

9

10

11

12

13
```

**What I'm being tested on, and should follow: **(the conditions)****

```
Test various parameters: '1'

OK

Test various parameters: '3 1 2'

OK

Test various parameters: 'numbers file variable'

OK

Test for calls to forbidden Python functions: 'input'

OK

Test for calls to forbidden Python functions: 'readlines'

ERROR:

function should not call 'readlines'

Test for calls to forbidden Python functions: 'open'

OK

Test for calls to forbidden Python functions: 'close'

OK

Test function docstring documentation:

OK

Test for multiple returns:

OK

Test that the function does not hard code the length of the file:

OK

Test for misuse of function name:

OK
```

Code:

```
def append_increment(fh):

    """
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Appends a number to the end of the fh. The number appended
    is the last number in the file plus 1.
    Assumes file is not empty.
    Use: num = append_increment(fh)
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Parameters:
        fh - file to search (file handle - already open for reading/writing)
    Returns:
        num - the number appended to the file (int)
    ------------------------------------------------------
    """
    fh.seek(0)
    file_contents = fh.readlines()
    num = int(file_contents[-1]) + 1
    fh.write(str(num))
    return num
```

**Sample testing:**

file 'numbers.txt' open for reading and writing

14 is appended

Comment: Cheaty solution is `list(fh)` instead of `fh.readlines()`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, you opened the file with the right mode ?
 I am using `'at+'` as mode right now and it works. Well you have to add a newline after each new number to avoid digit stacking. But that's no big issue.
Here is what I got so far:

```py
def append_increment(fh):
    fh.seek(0)
    file_contents = fh.readlines()
    num = int(file_contents[-1]) + 1
    fh.write(str(num) + "\n")   # don't forget a newline after every new number
    return num
  
fh = open ( 'increment-number-file.txt', 'at+' )
append_increment(fh)
fh.close()

print ( open ( 'increment-number-file.txt', 'rt' ).read() )
```

Comment: OP's issue is that the HW submission checks for certain banned functions (for some reason), not that the code doesn't work.